# Why do people use so caused in these sentences? Are they redundant or necessary?

Tags: sentence-construction

Saw these sentences in a booklet (large lift repairs & maintenance services)

> Sorry for the inconvenience so caused
>
> The problem between teens and parents is the lack of communication so caused?

Won't the meanings still be clear enough without so caused?

Comment: In what country do you see or hear this phrase used? It isn't used in spoken American English. It use peaked around 1900, according to Ngram. The phrase appears in legal and philosophical texts predominantly ("...no liability rests upon the person who so acts, and ... he is not answerable for the injury so caused").

Answer (score 1):

You are quite right, if "*so caused*" was dropped from either of your sentences, they would still be understood correctly.

For you first sentence

> Sorry for the inconvenience **so caused**.

is usually said as

> Sorry for any inconvenience caused.